# facebook isn't showing an og:image in debugger, even though it's a 206 code

Tags: facebook-opengraph, vercel, facebook-debugger

facebook debugger gives me no errors and a 206 code, but doesn't shows preview — even though an image works well at twitter, vk, telegram and signal

it seems that facebook had problems with https protocol, but it was many years ago — and i use vercel hosting, which doesn't use a http urls; also the hosting uses gzip encoding

i tried `image:secure_url` and `image:url` and they're doesn't work either

the image is 1200×630px and 796 KB
i also tried to save it as jpg and jpeg-2000

a link is — https://www.lgbtpropaganda.media/test_neyroset_ili_dolboyob.html

my meta tags:

```html
    <meta property="og:title" content="Тест: нейросеть или долбоёб / лгбт-пропаганда"/>
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Тест: нейросеть или долбоёб / лгбт-пропаганда">
    <meta property="og:description" content="17&nbsp;октября в&nbsp;государственной думе прошли слушания по&nbsp;законопроекту о&nbsp;запрете &laquo;пропаганды нетрадиционных сексуальных отношений&raquo;. Слушания, как всегда, отметились одиозными высказываниями депутатов. Предлагаем вам угадать, какие из&nbsp;этих цитат настоящие, а&nbsp;какие&nbsp;&mdash; работа нейросетей" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="17&nbsp;октября в&nbsp;государственной думе прошли слушания по&nbsp;законопроекту о&nbsp;запрете &laquo;пропаганды нетрадиционных сексуальных отношений&raquo;. Слушания, как всегда, отметились одиозными высказываниями депутатов. Предлагаем вам угадать, какие из&nbsp;этих цитат настоящие, а&nbsp;какие&nbsp;&mdash; работа нейросетей">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://lgbtpropaganda.media/test_neyroset_ili_dolboyob.html"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://lgbtpropaganda.media/img/test_neyroset_ili_dolboyob_og.png" />
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://lgbtpropaganda.media/img/test_neyroset_ili_dolboyob_og.png">
    <meta data-rh="true" property="og:image:width" content="1200">
    <meta data-rh="true" property="og:image:height" content="630">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="ru-RU" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

[image: how it looks in the debugger —]